# Pagination problem in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

For some reason the pagination is not working here, and I can't figure out why.

```
<?php

    if ( get_query_var('paged') )
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) 
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
    else 
    $paged = 1;

    $post_type = 'portfolio';
    $tax = 'type';
    $tax_terms = get_terms($tax);

    ?>

    <?php 

    //print_r($tax_terms);
    if ($tax_terms) {
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {

    $args = array (

        'post_type' => $post_type,
        "$tax" => $tax_term->slug,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
        'paged' => $paged 

        );  


    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);


    ?>

    <?php if ( $my_query->have_posts () ) { ?>

    <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts () ) : $my_query->the_post(); $count++; global $post;  ?>

    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/_framework/includes/portContent.php'); ?>      

    <?php endwhile;?>

    <?php }  ?>

    <?php }  ?>

    <?php }  ?>

   <?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
    pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
    } ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: The pagination disappears altogether.  It doesn't recognize the posts_per_page at all.  Here's an example of it not working.  http://s51370.gridserver.com/blank/test  No error messages, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Comment: That didn't seem to have an effect.  I removed `if ( get_query_var('paged') )
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) 
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
    else 
    $paged = 1;
`  And replaced it with `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`  and the pagination doesn't show at all.  the filter functionality still works, however.

Comment: try using default pagination links of wordpress first and see if it works or not.  `previous_posts_link(); next_posts_link();`

Comment: And also why you place the while in foreach loop. What you are trying to accomplish? thanks!

Comment: I tried the original pagination, just to be sure.  The pagination function I'm using works, typically.  The purpose of this code is to use a taxonomy (type) within the loop for filtering.  You can see this working here, but the pagination is not.  http://s51370.gridserver.com/blank/port1  Thanks!